# Choosing PouchDB adapters for PC and AWS

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I need to solve an offline synch problem and PouchDB seems to be a good fit.

My client is a PC and my server needs to run on AWS. I am happy to work in node.js on the client.

From reading the documentation, it seems that the recommended configuration would be to use the WebSQL adapter on the client side and CouchDB (or Cloudant) on the server side since it is most "battle proven" adapter.

Q1) Since I am on AWS, would I be better off using an adapter to DynamoDB even if it is less "battle tested"?

Q2) Why isn't running the couchDB adapter also on the client side not a better option than using the WebSQL adapter? Is this even an option?

Comment: Q2: If you use the offline capabilities of PouchDB for mobile, you normally can't have a local CouchDB instance. For this reason, you usually use browser's embedded database. Of course you can use CouchDB on the client directly but you have to install CouchDB on the client's system.

Comment: @Alexis when you write "directly" do you mean not through pouchDB? Does PouchDB still help me with offline sync if I run CouchDB on both sides?

Comment: Well, if your clients have CouchDB, you can use any CouchDB client library. All the sync capabilities are implemented in CouchDB. PouchDB his only a JavaScript API to use it but it also implements CouchDB functionnalities into different datastore (IndexedDB, WebSql..)